# GPU Driver issues, emulator error

Tags: virtual-machine, driver, gpu, emulation, android-virtual-device

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/545Ve.png)

hello, i have that problem with the "GPU Driver issues" in past when i open the emulator it work well but after month or two  i installed the adnroidStudio again and that ennoyning problomlem jump, i searched for solution in this web and found two solution.
1. to updates beta channel (from "setting" in the file in android studio)->didnt work....

2. to go to C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator
   Find emulator to run by listing available ones: emulator -list-avds
   Run emulator with -gpu host option: emulator -avd avd_name -gpu host
   but when i opened the emulator file i didnt fount that files ("emulator -list-avds" and "emulator -avd avd_name -gpu host")

look at this...

[whre is the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYX8b.png)

(you can see in the pic up^^^ that "emulator -list-avds" and "emulator -avd avd_name -gpu host"  is not in the emulator file)

someone can help me please?
I traide to solve it more than 2 weeks.. no idea what to do now..
thanks for the helper

Comment: p.s.
i traied to install new version of driver for intel---->didnt work
i traied to installed the beta version of android studio--->didnt work

importent to mention that i am very new at that kind of work so its mybe that i have no idea what i did and just waisted my time in attention to fix it, and if you can please write your answer so i can understand it, thats mean like you explain and tutorial litlle child.
thank you very mutch!